# Изменить имя пользователя во время предпросмотра в TicketComments

Tags: modx, revo

Здравствуйте, друзья!
Прикручиваю Tickets (TicketComments) на сайт под Modx Revo для комментариев и возникла вот какая сложность. 
В форме для отправки комментария есть поле для ввода имени автора комментария

```
<input type="text" class="text form-control" name="name" id="comment-name" value="[[+name]]" placeholder="Ваше имя"/>
```

Когда пользователь не авторизован, то во время предпросмотра указывается значение из поля name выше. Когда же пользователь авторизован — указывается его полное имя из профиля. 
Мой вопрос: где найти шаблон для вывода текста превью, чтобы поменять там имя на то, которое пользователь вводит в форме и если нельзя, то каким это сделать плагином? onBeforeCommentPublish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Победил. Создал копию файла default.js у Tickets,поменял в системных настройках путь на путь до копии.
внутри файла нашел

```
comment: {
        preview: function(form,button) {

            //Сохраняю имя из формы коммента

            var trueName = $(form).find("#comment-name").val();

            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                data: {action: 'comment/preview'}
                ,url: TicketsConfig.actionUrl
                ,form: form
                ,button: button
                ,dataType: 'json'
                ,beforeSubmit: function(formData, form, options) {
                    Tickets.comment.addAttachmentsToText(form, formData);
                    $(button).attr('disabled','disabled');
                    return true;
                }
                ,success: function(response) {
                    $(button).removeAttr('disabled');
                    if (response.success) {
                        $('#comment-preview-placeholder').html(response.data.preview).show();

                       //Меняю имя в тексте плейсхолдера

                        $('#comment-preview-placeholder').find('.ticket-comment-author').text(trueName);
                        prettyPrint();
                    }
                    else {
                        Tickets.Message.error(response.message);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```